# How to make Instaclustr Kafka Sink Connector work with Avro serialized value to postgres?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka topic of Avro-serialized value.

I am trying to set up a JDBC(postgres) sink connector to dump these messages in the postgres table.

But, I am getting below error.

```
"org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter for configuration value.converter: Class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter could not be found."
```

My Sink.json is

```
{"name": "postgres-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "topics": "<topic_name>",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "instaclustr_schema_registry_host:8085",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres?currentSchema=local",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "postgres",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "auto.evolve":"true",
    "pk.mode":"none",
    "table.name.format": "<table_name>"
  }
}
```

Also, I have made changes in the connect-distributed.properties(bootstrap servers).

The command I am running is -

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @postgres-sink.json https://<instaclustr_schema_registry_host>:8083/connectors
```

Answer (score 2):

`io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter` is not part of the Apache Kafka distribution. You can either just run Apache Kafka as part of Confluent Platform (which ships with the converter and is easier) or you can [download it separately](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-connect-avro-converter) and install it yourself.